# How can I grey out/disable a button on an Access form until something has been clicked?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, button, disabled-control

I'm still new to VBA and was wondering how I could grey out a command until another command has run? I'll include a picture below, but basically I want to have step 2 disabled until step 1 is complete (and step 3 disabled until step 2 is complete, etc.). I have steps 1-4 written on the side, but I want to diminish as much confusion and possible slip-ups as possible.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the screenshot of my form.

[image]

Comment: `Me.[ButtonNameHere].enabled = True`

Comment: Set the property `Enabled` of the buttons 2 to 4 to `False` in design mode, then in button_Click code do what @Warcupine says.

Comment: @warcupine Thank you, I figured it out. I added a ```public sub Form_load()``` that disabled the buttons, then upon clicking the first button, it enables the next three.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes This works, however it only works on the first new form I enter. When I click the "Add Record" button from the image I posted, I have the form automatically direct to a new form record. On this new record, the buttons are still enabled. Do you know how to disable them again?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes scratch that (sorry). I figured it out. I just added the ```Me.[buttonname].enabled = False``` to the event procedure for the ```add_record_click()```